Informatica-How to limit number of rows from Mainframe source
For relational databases we can limit the number of rows using SQL Transformation in Source Qualifier. Is there any similar way we can do for Mainframe Source?

Correction: to limit the number of rows, you should use Source Filter property, not the SQL Query. Now, having said that: is there a Source Filter property in your Source Qualifier?
